# Docker Dockerfile NGINX with phpBB not showing data from /var/www/ directory

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, phpbb3

I've the following Dockerfile https://github.com/SeppPenner/docker-nginx-ssl-secure (a original NGINX container with SSL forked from https://github.com/MarvAmBass/docker-nginx-ssl-secure).

```
FROM nginx:latest

MAINTAINER SeppPenner

RUN apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y wget; \
    apt-get install -y unzip; \
    apt-get install -y openssl

RUN wget https://www.phpbb.com/files/release/phpBB-3.2.2.zip

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/

RUN unzip phpBB-3.2.2.zip -d /var/www/; \
    rm phpBB-3.2.2.zip

RUN cd /var/www/phpBB3; \
    chmod 666 config.php; \
    chmod 777 store/; \
    chmod 777 cache/; \
    chmod 777 files/; \
    chmod 777 images/avatars/upload/

ENV LANG C.UTF-8

RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d/*; \
    mkdir -p /etc/nginx/external

RUN sed -i 's/access_log.*/access_log \/dev\/stdout;/g' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf; \
    sed -i 's/error_log.*/error_log \/dev\/stdout info;/g' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf; \
    sed -i 's/^pid/daemon off;\npid/g' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

ADD basic.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/basic.conf
ADD ssl.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf

ADD entrypoint.sh /opt/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod a+x /opt/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["nginx"]
```

I now wanted to run phpBB in this container, too. It seems to work but the problem is that I can't access the webserver over the browser with e.g. typing `https://192.168.2.206/phpBB3` into the URL bar. Does anyone have an idea here?

Comment: -2? Seriously? Ok^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now used the following docker container and it worked: https://github.com/blueimp/phpbb/issues/1